# unix bash shell script writing

Tags: unix

How to write a bash shell script that accepts 5 different integer values as command line arguments and displays the smallest, the largest and the middle argument. the script uses: An if statement. The *if* statement should give an error message if the number of arguments is not exactly 5 and then it executes the exit command to end the script.

A push in the right direction or something would greatly be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Have you started this exercise yourself? With which parts of the script are you struggling?

Comment: Is this homework - if so please tag it as such.

Comment: This is almost certainly homework.

Comment: @jabbie: [Why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starter for you, giving you all of the constructs you'll need but without doing the exercise for you...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if (( ${#@} == 5 )); then
    echo "Correct number of arguments, I'll now play with ${@}, starting with $1 and ending with $5..."
elif (( ${#@} < 5 )); then
    echo $(( 5 - ${#@} )) " more arguments needed."
elif (( ${#@} > 5 )); then
    echo $(( ${#@} - 5 )) " fewer arguments needed."
fi
```

If you run through the [Bash Scripting Tutorial](http://www.linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial), you should be able to do this in no time at all!